# Slide views up when soft keyboard is shown

Tags: java, android

I want to slide my form views up when the soft keyboard is appeared.
I found out that is not as easy as I thought, I've tried to change the activity's `windowSoftInputMode` to `adjustPan` and it do nothing, then I tried to change it to `adjustResize` and it just resized my button's height.

Example of my desired result:

[image: Soft keyboard is hidden]

And when the user clicks on one of the Edit Text views I want those views to slide up:

[image: Soft keyboard is visible]

**Edit**: Here is my layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.invity.Login"
android:background="#5dc8fc"
android:id="@+id/rlLogin">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:background="#5dc8fc"
style="@style/AppBaseThemeNoTitle" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBG1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="matrix"
        android:src="@drawable/BG1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgBG2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/BG2" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="190dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_white"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="@string/app_login_Email_Hint"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogo"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textDirection="ltr"
    android:textColor="#58c9f3"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="@string/app_login_Password_Hint"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmail"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:ems="15"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textDirection="ltr"
    android:textColor="#58c9f3"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnConnect"
    android:layout_width="350dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtPassword"
    android:text="@string/app_login_btn"
    android:onClick="btnLoginClick"
    android:background="@drawable/button_style"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have 2 ImageViews that put together the background.

Comment: can you show your layout file. adjustResize should be what you are looking for

Comment: It's just resize my button. Maybe it's because the 2 Imageviews behind the views?

Comment: see here: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard/34263560#34263560)

Answer (score -1):

you need to requestFocus();

if you cant request focus u can use

```
(!EditText.hasFocus()){
//do nothing}
else{EditText.requestFocus();}
```

in some sort of update method

Comment: Thanks, but it's not relevant to my question.